# Missing field descriptions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Somehow, even though I have "Descriptions" ticked in the properties area, I've managed to somehow collapse the field descriptions area and it's not visible at the bottom of the properties window. There doesn't seem to be a "split" handle to drag upward, either (believe me, I've tried!).

Does anyone know how to get the field descriptions back?

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Properties window with no field descriptions]

Answer (score 2):

By complete chance, I happened across the solution:

I left the properties window open and went to a code pane, and a blank field descriptions box appeared:

[image: Properties window with text editor showing blank field description box]

Dragging it upward reset the location of that splitter, making them visible again when viewing a designer:

[image: Fixed properties window with field descriptions back]

Hopefully that will help someone else searching (as I did) to get their field descriptions back!