# Visual Studio - Properties Window - Field Descriptions IS EMPTY

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have this problem for some time now.

In Visual Studio 2017 & 2019, in the Properties Window,
the description is empty for all the properties fields.

[image: Properties Window]

How do I show/display them back again,

example:

[image: Field Decribtion]

Thanks for your help.

PS: I have tried the following solutions, but nothing worked for me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/misc/getting-field-descriptions-from-the-properties-window?view=vs-2015

[How do I show the description box of the properties window in Visual Studio 2010 if it is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381555/how-do-i-show-the-description-box-of-the-properties-window-in-visual-studio-2010?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Property description panel missing from WPF project property window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798092/property-description-panel-missing-from-wpf-project-property-window-in-visual-st?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Missing field descriptions in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213277/missing-field-descriptions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Tried reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, especially VS219 I have just installed it 2 days ago.